# renderUI, load data then render a new UI in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This might be very simple. But when a reactive value change I would like to render a UI from server.R, then load some data, run some functions and then render a new UI. However I can't seem to get it to work, as it just waits 2 sek and then shows the last renderUI (not showing the loadUI in the meantime).

I know I can use shinyJS (https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/loading-screen) for this, however for what I'm doing I would like to show a totally new page, load my data, and then show another new page.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "btn_data", label = "Load Data"),
  uiOutput("page")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(loaddata = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$btn_data, {
    rv$loaddata <- TRUE
  })

  observe({

    if(rv$loaddata){

      #Page to show, when loading data - loadUI
      output$page <- renderUI({
        p("Loading data...")
      })

      #Running functions and loading data
      Sys.sleep(2)

      #Page to show when data is loaded
      output$page <- renderUI({
        p("Data is now loaded")
      })

    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about the exact outcome you want? In the example, press the button, and then what?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. When btn_data is pressed I want it to render "Loading data..." in uiOutput("page"), the run the code (in this example 'Sys.sleep(2)') and then when the code has run, render the "Data is now loaded" part in the uiOutput. Does that make sense? :-)